# Visual Studio 2015 pervasively displaying purple squigglies with empty light bulbs in comments

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 is displaying purple squiggly underlines with empty light bulbs in comments. I've yet to discover the root cause.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a spellcheck extension installed? That might be what's giving you these lines.

Answer (score 0):

ComponentOne IntelliSpell was the culprit.